# Change backColor of Repeater Button onClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, repeater

I have Repeater buttons that i want to change their backcolor on click.
The problem is that I dont know how to identify which button is clicked and I cant reach it through the onclick function.
Just to make it clear - I want to change the button that has been clicked.
It should be like a "selected" button.

THOSE ARE THE BUTTONS

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFillButtonCategory" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="FillButton" runat="server" Width="100%" OnClick="ButtonSelectionFill" 
             CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' 
             Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") + " for next version" %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is the on click function

```
public void ButtonSelectionFill(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = ((Button)o);
    btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    DropCategory.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt16(((Button)o).CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
            Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    b.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try it in a separate, simple web form containing only the repeater and see where it breaks.

Comment: It doesn't help me so much

Comment: It means that the backcolor doesnt change.

Comment: Can you see the buttons?

Comment: Are there any exception being thrown in the `Output` windows in Visual Studio?

Comment: listen, it should be ok . i think the problem is that it renders the page or something